# good tire pressure for agressive driving

Tags: tires, pressure

Apparently my current rear tire (talon, some cheap brand) seems to be out of round lately. I have been replacing it with the same tire from the same brand and I notice that every time I drive on deep potholes, they seem to be out of round afterwards. 
I'm not exactly the best driver, so I usually drive fast on potholes so I could get past them quicker. Recently I was driving on the mountains, and as I reached the top of a hill/mountain, I have not noticed a pothole, so I went in  at 35-40mph, and I think it caused the problem with my tire.

The recommended tire pressure I think for my car is 32psi, but I opt to put it to 35psi, for better fuel economy and so I could really feel my tires.

I do use dunlop for my front tires, and I might consider replacing the rear with dunlops as well.

What can I do with my tires to prevent them from being out of round whilst at the same time maintaining my driving style?

Comment: Lowering the pressure to 32 or even 30 psi is a good start.

Comment: What do you mean by "out of round"? Uneven wear along the surface or bumps on the tire? A higher pressure than the one specified by the vehicle manufacturer is usually not an issue and supposedly recommended by some tire manufacturers. You refer to your "rear tire", but your "front tires", but afaik this goes for both cars and bikes. I purposely do it on both and have had no issues because of it. Under-inflation is what makes things go scary (not considering snow and ice).

Comment: bumps on the tire, what I mean by rear tires, is that they are the ones having issues, and my front tires have no problem at all since I'm using quality brand tires up front. I had the alignment checked a couple of weeks ago and there seems to be no problem with it.

Comment: @Juann Strauss however if I lowered my tire pressure, I can definitely feel the increase in fuel consumption. I always fill up half tank and it would cost me more if I lowered the pressure than replacing the tire. However it seems that the tires tend to go out of round at around 500km, and that really infuriates me.

Comment: If you drive like you live a quarter mile at a time, why do you even care about fuel consumption?

Comment: Going with the manufacturer recommended pressure would be a start vehicle and tire manufacturers put a lot more time and resources into determining what specification is best than a group of guys on the Internet ever will and anyone that says otherwise is either through experience in a very specific use case or just flat out wrong so I'd say 32 would probably be the best seeing as it's a rating based on tons of hard data and research in all types of conditions

Answer (score 1):

check bushes on top and bottom of your shock absorber.As this only occurs on one wheel
it's a definite possibility.I much prefer rubber bushes for aggressive driving.Given
only four hand prints of rubber are between you and eternity why buy cheap tyres built
down to a price not up to a standard.Not knowing your vehicle or tyre construction it
is hard to provide a definitive answer.As an example;offroad tyres of light truck construction at correct pressure are very forgiving.Reputable tyre makers provide an
online calculator to inform you as to recommended tyre pressure/speed/terrain.Note-
high speed and low pressure=heat and possible tyre failure